# Remove Selected Days from Material Calendar View

Tags: java, android, material-ui, calendar

So I have been trying to remove Selected days from material Calendar and also remove their decorators but I couldn't figure out how to do that using **removeDecorator()**.

Instead I created an extra  xml file to **decorate** the **removed days**.

I'll post the solution below in case anyone needs it. If anyone knows a better way to do this , please leave a comment with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

#### class MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialCalendarView calendarView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendar);
        ArrayList<CalendarDay> dates = new ArrayList<CalendarDay>();
        
        calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {

                if (dates.contains(calendarView.getSelectedDate())) {
                    dates.remove(calendarView.getSelectedDate());
                    calendarView.addDecorator(new SelectedDayDecorator(2,calendarView.getSelectedDates(), MainActivity.this));
                } else {
                    dates.add(calendarView.getSelectedDate());
                    calendarView.addDecorator(new SelectedDayDecorator(1,dates, MainActivity.this));
                }
            }
        });

        calendarView.setSelectionColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
    }
}
```

#### class SelectedDayDecorator

```
public class SelectedDayDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {
    Context sContext ;
    private int color;
    private HashSet<CalendarDay> dates;

    public SelectedDayDecorator(Collection<CalendarDay> dates,Context context) {
        this.dates = new HashSet<>(dates);
        this.sContext = context;
        this.color = color;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        return dates.contains(day);
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        int drawable = R.drawable.selected_day_color;
        view.addSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK));
        if (color == 1) {
            view.setSelectionDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(sContext, R.drawable.selected_day_color));
        } else if (color == 2){
      view.setSelectionDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(sContext,R.drawable.default_day_color));
    }
    }
}
```

#### drawable selected_day_color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="1dp"
    android:insetLeft="1dp"
    android:insetRight="1dp"
    android:insetTop="1dp">

    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="50dp"
            android:color="@color/teal_700" />
        <size
            android:width="10dp"
            android:height="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

#### drawable default_day_color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetBottom="1dp"
    android:insetLeft="1dp"
    android:insetRight="1dp"
    android:insetTop="1dp">

    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="50dp"
            android:color="@color/transparent" />
        <size
            android:width="10dp"
            android:height="10dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

Comment: Another simpler way of doing it is by using `calendarView.removeDecorators();` in Main Activity in the first if inside `onDateSelected`. You remove the decorators and then adding again the decorator to the dates arraylist.